# Remote access to Kafka

Tags: confluent-platform

I'm not able to access kafka which is in remote server from my local server.
I tried to set parameter **advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ip:port**  in server.properties of kafka where ip is the public ip of my remote machine where kafka is. But still I'm not able to connect. What should I need to do next? I'm using confluent kafka of version 3.3.0.

Comment: Is this on Cloud (AWS) or your own network? When you say "I'm not able to connect", do you get an error?

Comment: AWS machine. The error is brockers are not available.